# Would I have problems entering the USA with an VWP-eligible passport if I have entered before with a non-VWP-eligible passport?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I have entered the USA with my non-VWP-eligible Passport.  I would now like to enter the country under the Visa Waiver Program with my VWP-eligible passport and an ESTA. I would Like to know if the custom officer could deny my entrance if I had put "no" to the question in the ESTA application do you have any other nationalities other than this one (VWP-eligible passport)

Comment: As I understand your question, you have two nationalities, but want to apply for an ESTA saying that you only have one nationality? Why? Or did you already apply for an ESTA and provide false information? Or have you lost your other nationality in the meantime? Or have I completely misunderstood your question?

Comment: Ok, the next time someone advises you to provide false information to the US government, turn around and run far away. I realize there are many parts of the world where it's common, sometimes even necessary, to provide false documents, but the US is very much not one of those places, and the consequences can be severe. Do you know why the tourism company told you to provide false information? Is this perhaps due to one of your other nationalities being Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan?

Comment: I don't really know why, and no it's not any of the countries you mentioned! but thanks for the information! :)

Comment: If you have actually formally renounced or been stripped of your old citizenship (and now have only a single VWP-eligible one), then obviously you *can* (and, in fact, must) answer "no", but you still need to disclose your previous trip if they ask about it. They are humans there and they do understand that sometimes people lose citizenships. They don't have a problem with that. They *do* have a problem with false statements and tend to get *really mad* when they realize that someone has lied to them. Don't do this. I'm so seriously.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a problem at all, the fact that you entered on a visa using another passport before can only help if it has any impact at all.

However the fact that you have misstated your nationalities on the ESTA application can definitely be troublesome.

> **What should a traveler do if the information in his or her passport has changed?**
>
> If a traveler’s passport information changes, the individual is required to apply for a new travel authorization through ESTA. A new travel authorization is required if (1) the traveler is issued a new passport; (2) the traveler changes his or her name; (3) the traveler changes his or her gender; (4) the traveler’s country of citizenship changes; or (5) the circumstances underlying the traveler’s previous responses to any of the ESTA application questions requiring a “yes” or “no” response have changed. The associated fee will be charged for each new application submitted.

Source: [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel)

**I would reapply for a fresh ESTA**.

Comment: Thanks! So it will be better if I re-enter the ESTA application in this case right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. An ESTA obtained with important information concealed from the application can easily become a recipe for a quick return flight from the airport. However, i don't know if you can reapply for an ESTA while you hold an existing ESTA.

Comment: Yes. Disclosing this is pretty easy. If you want to enter the USA on your VWP-eligible Austrian passport but you are also a Ukrainian citizen, you just disclose this. Apply with your Austrian passport, and then say YES, you have another citizenship, Ukraine. This doesn't make you ineligible. Lying is *highly likely* to make you ineligible, and if you have already *been* to the USA on your other passport, it is highly likely that they know about it already. Don't lie. Liars get sent home.

Comment: If your other citizenship is a country that is really disfavored by the USA, like Iran or North Korea, there could *possibly* be an issue (see an immigration attorney), but disclosing is still far better. If your other citizenship is just an ordinary non-VWP eligible country like Pakistan, China, or Mali, that's not a problem at all. Just disclose.

Comment: So if my other passport is a non-VWP eligible (which country ends up being Argentina) I would end up having no problems?

Comment: Yes. Why do you expect there would be problems?

Comment: No, there's no problem with also being an Argentinian citizen. Just apply for an ESTA with your VWP-eligible passport, and when asked if you have any other citizenships, say yes, Argentina. This is very common.